# Setup for ASP.NET MVC and Javascript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My JavaScript will not run. I've been struggling with this for a while (2 days) Here's my current setup:

Created a new MVC 4 project. I intend to try out some AJAX, so named it AjaxTest.
Added a model (Vehicle.cs) consisting of three classes OdometerInfo, VehicleMinInfo, and Vehicle. Here they are:

```
public class OdometerInfo
{
    public virtual string VIN { get; set;  }
    public virtual int Odometer { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleMinInfo : OdometerInfo
{
    public virtual Nullable<int> VehicleYear { get; set; }
    public virtual string Make { get; set; }
    public virtual string Model { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle : VehicleMinInfo
{
    // default constructor
    public Vehicle()
    {
        VIN = "MyFakeVin";
        Odometer = 0;
        VehicleYear = 2012;
        Make = "Porsche";
        Model = "911";
    }

    public override string VIN { get; set; }
    public override int Odometer { get; set; }

    public override Nullable<int> VehicleYear { get; set; }
    public override string Make { get; set; }
    public override string Model { get; set; }

    // other fields
}
```

Then I replaced the contents of the template Index.cshtml with:

```
@model AjaxTest.Models.VehicleMinInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Enter your odometer reading</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Odometer", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <h4>For the following vehicle.</h4>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.VIN) <br />
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.VehicleYear) <br />
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Make) <br />
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Model) <br />
    <h1>Enter Odometer</h1>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Odometer)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Odometer)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.VIN);
    <input type="submit" value="Odometer reading is correct" id="OdometerForm" />
}
```

Then I made a strongly typed view (Odometer.cshtml):

```
@model AjaxTest.Models.OdometerInfo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Odometer";
}

<h2>Odometer</h2>
Your odometer has been entered. It is
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Odometer)
. (
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.VIN)
)
```

And added to the controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        VehicleMinInfo OdomObj = new Vehicle();
        return View(OdomObj);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Odometer(OdometerInfo oi)
    {
        return View(oi);
    }
```

All of that works. I can fill in an odometer reading and both the odometer and the VIN are passed back to the controller and displayed on the Odometer page. Now, it's time to start adding some JavaScript. So I created OdometerList.js with the eventual goal of passing back a list of odometer readings instead of just one, and in it I placed:

```
$("#OdometerForm").click(function () {
    alert("Hello world!");
});

window.onload = function () {
    if (window.jQuery) {
        // jQuery is loaded  
        alert("Yeah!");
    } else {
        // jQuery is not loaded
        alert("Doesn't Work");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("!!!");
});
```

Then I added in _Layout.cshtml

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/OdometerList.js")
```

And I double checked Web.config to be sure compilation debug was true:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    ...
```

None of my alerts are triggered, not one. Is my setup wrong? I moved my JavaScript from OdometerList.js to the bottom of Odometer.cshtml and put it all between script tags, but there was no change. I am new to JavaScript, so have I made a mistake there?

This is really stumping me. Any help you can give will be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked the console to see if you have any errors?

Comment: No. How would I do that?

Comment: Every browser comes with a set of development tools which includes a javascript console where you can see all kind of javascipt (and html and css) related information like errors. These developer tools can be access with hitting F12 in IE and Chrome. For Firefox you need to install an extension called FireBug to have the same set of tools.

Comment: Yes, I do have an error. "SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined". JavaScript is installed as part of MVC templates, right? Do I have to do something special to make sure JavaScript is installed? (Thanks for the helpful comment!)

Comment: When did you have this error? When you used the suggestion from my answer or with your original code? Other than that jquery is included in the default mvc project templates, but not necessary the version `jquery-1.3.2.min.js`. Please check that your in MVC project there is a `Scripts` directory which contains the `jquery-1.3.2.min.js` and a `OdometerList.js`. It is not enough to have them in the file system they have to included in the Visual Studio project so you need to see them inside in VS. Maybe you have a different jquery version so you need to use that one in your view.

Comment: Yes. There is a scripts directory in the project, not just in the file system. It has 17 js files in it, including OdometerList.js and jquery-1.3.2.min.js. The error happened in both cases. When I used my original code and when I used plain script tags.

Comment: You can also try `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js")"></script><script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/OdometerList.js")"></script>`. Tou also check in your browser dev tools: there should a network tab where you can the requests made to your server and there should be an entry which tries to download `/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js` can you check that? There should not be error and status code should be 200.

Comment: Cool. I'm learning about the tools I need for debugging! I clicked "Start capturing" on the Network tab. I got a 404 error. I guess there's the reason jquery is not defined. Now if I could just figure out how to fix it...

Comment: Got it! The version of jQuery I am using was updated from 1.3.2 to 1.8.2. Once I changed the name of the file in _Layout.cshtml everything started working. I missed it even going over it several times (3 and 8 look so similar...yeah, that must be it!).

Comment: nemesv, Your help was the key to answering this question. If you put your comment above (about jquery version) in an answer, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of jQuery had been updated. Once I put the correct version number in, I was able to use @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js") and everything works!